# Autodesk v1 setreference functionality in v2

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

The Autodesk v1 API is deprecated as of [July 17 2017.](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/09/autodesk-forge-apis-migrating-from-v1-to-v2.html?utm_swu=3721&utm_medium=email&utm_source=swu&utm_campaign=forge_developer_newsletter_jan_2017) The v2 API does not appear support [setting references between part files](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/08/how-to-set-references-with-autocad-files-for-view-and-data-api.html) as currently provided by the `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/references/v1/setreference` endpoint.

How can one set references between part files so an assembly can be translated using the v2 Model Derivative api? The answer must explicitly not make use of the ability to upload a zip containing all files to the api. A zip of all files is not an option in my case.

Comment: Hi @sabrehagen, as I remember, we had a discussion for one issue of setting reference by v1 in the other post. Sorry I forgot why zip option is not fine in your requirements. Could you share a bit more comments then I can forward to our engineer team to evaluate? Thank you.

Comment: my colleague reminded me that the only workaround currently is to use an A360 based account where you can set up references between individual files. This is a blog that tells more: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/setting-up-references-between-files .  Will this be fine to you?

Comment: The api suggested in the article references `/data/v1/projects/:projectId/`. This means a project is needed to set up references. This means we must purchase a BIM 360 Team subscription to access that api. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

It has been quite a while, yet the web web service has been exposed: 
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-references-POST/
by which, we can set the reference of files manually. for reference of future visitors.